# Way to automatically change fields used across multiple queries

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

Im using MS Access 2003 and within it I have maybe 100 queries in total; I've been tasked with changing a few names in one of the tables and I don't know exactly how many queries use that particular table.

My question is - is there anyway in Access to automatically change the field names in a table used in multiple queries without having to manually update the queries to reflect the change?

For example say query A does this:

```
SELECT name
FROM tblA
WHERE ...
```

If i changed the name in the table is there a way to reflect this across all the queries?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is about the only case where Track Name Autocorrect and Perform Name Autocorrect is a good idea.

> Why should I use name AutoCorrect? When you work in a database that
>   has a design that is frequently changed by users, database objects can
>   stop working if the design of other database objects changes. One way
>   this can occur is when the name of an object changes, but that change
>   is not accompanied by corresponding changes to objects that depend on
>   the original object.
>
> For example, if you create a query that is based on a table named
>   Customers, and the name of the table is later changed to Customer, the
>   query that you created stops working because of this name change.
>   Nothing else is wrong with the query, and if you correct the table
>   name in the query design, the query works again.
>
> The name AutoCorrect feature can track name changes for you, and can
>   automatically correct the names of forms, reports, tables, queries,
>   fields, or controls, such as text boxes.

-- http://office.microsoft.com/en-ie/access-help/set-name-autocorrect-options-HA010256413.aspx